Amcharts stacked bar spacing
I am having issues with my stacked bar chart using amCharts 5. I cannot get space added between the blocks in the stacked columns. I cannot locate anywhere in the code where you can specify spacing or at least a min height for the lower numbers that are hardly visible. I am trying to create a custom theme but I can't seem to get that to work either.

